# Android Studio: R file not getting updated

Tags: android, android-studio, developer-tools

Upon creating a new menu resource file, the auto-generated R file is not getting updated. This causes syntax error when I try to use it the following way:

`getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)`

Attaching a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7R5.png) for more clarity.

Comment: i have tried to make a folder or make a new android resource file in res/menu, i also try with another name called main, but the problem is not in the name of my file but the R.(menu) is not defined, please tell me how to fix it

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

in the new android, can sometimes unrecognized faulty `Id` in `xml` or `file xml`. 
I have met several such cases. 
My solutions are `close and open` the project. you can try it. 
Hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can just invalidate and restart android studio even if it keep asking ignore and just run it.

[image: View Image 1]

[image: View Image 2]